# jQuery: submit form after a value is selected from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

I have this form in my HTML:

```
<form action="/awe/ChangeTheme/Change" method="post">

    <select id="themes" name="themes">
        ...
        <option value="blitzer">blitzer</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="change" />

</form>
```

Anybody knows how to submit it when a value is selected in the 'themes' dropdown?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The other solutions will submit **all** forms on the page, if there should be any. Better would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#themes').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have multiple forms it would be even better if you replace the third line with: $(this).parent('form').submit();

Comment: @PeterdeRidder `this.form` already does that and more, because `$(this).parent('form')` only works if the form is the direct parent of the select, which it often isn't.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#themes').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

In case your html contains more than one form

```
$(function() {
  $('#themes').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form')
           .trigger('submit')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the longhand bind method because it has the same effect as the shorthand supplied by the other answers, but you can add additional events if need be without having to change your code.

```
$("#themes").bind("change", function() {
  $("form").trigger("submit");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#themes').change(function() {
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
   $('#your_select_field_id').on('change', function(e) {
      $('#your_form_id').submit();
   })
})
```

This solved my problem efficiently.